# Access a Tomcat local server using android device

Tags: android, localhost, tomcat7

I have a Tomcat server running on Localhost. My app can access it in the emulator using 10.0.0.2:8080. But when I connect a device it can't access the server.

I've seen some similar questions but couldn't get this working. can someone give me the steps on what to do?

Comment: What exception is thrown upon the connection attempt? Please do not comment. Instead, edit your question.

Comment: Are both, the PC and the phone connected to the same network?

Comment: What's the phone's IP in that network?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

we use 10.0.2.2:8081 because 127.0.0.1 is reserved for the emulator, however, when you need to try the application through a real device you need to change the URL to your PC IP

go to CMD and run ipconfig, look for IPv4 address, this IP you will use it..

add it to the URL for example:  http://192.somethin.somthin.somthing:8081/the-location.php

**P.S: you should set your firewall off and turn off any antivirus**

Comment: thanks! it's working now. couldn't figure out this simple thing and wasted much time.

Answer (score 0):

The device may not be on the same network as the Tomcat server.  Does your network provide VPN access?  If so, try installing an Android VPN client (Junos Pulse is a good free one).  Connect your device to VPN and try again.

10.0.0.2 looks like an internal address.  The emulator is likely able to connect because the machine on which it is running is connected to the network.  The actual device needs a direct connection as well.  VPN should solve that.